# Hiding rows, looping worksheets

Tags: loops, excel, hide, vba

I aim to enter formulas in A:A and 1:1 that are either blank or 'HIDE' - when HIDE is there is hides the row/column. I aim to write vba code to loop through each worksheet and do all HIDE commands.

I have written the following and it isn't working, it only performs the hide command on one sheet. Can you help?

```
Sub hide()

Dim Ver As Range, Hor As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    Set Ver = Range("A2:A300")
    Set Hor = Range("B2:JA1")


    For Each cel In Ver
       If cel.Value = "HIDE" Then
          cel.EntireRow.Hidden = True
       End If
    Next cel
    For Each cel In Hor
       If cel.Value = "HIDE" Then
          cel.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
       End If
    Next cel

    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Try qualifying your range with the sheet like this: `Set Ver = ws.Range("A2:A300")` instead of this `Set Ver = Range("A2:A300")`

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the parent of the ranges you are looking at as you cycle through the worksheets.

```
Set Ver = ws.Range("A2:A300")
For Each cel In Ver
    ...
Set Hor = ws.Range("B2:JA1")
For Each cel In Hor
    ...
```

This will redefine the parent worksheet for each cycle through the `For each in` loop. I would also advise explicitly setting ws to nothing before exiting the loop. e.g. just before `Exit Sub`,

```
    ...
Next ws
Set Ver = nothing
Set Hor = nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to achieve this using For-each loops, I highly recommend you to avoid this approach.

The quickest, cleanest and safest solution is to take advantage of SpecialCells.

```
Range("A2:A300").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

What this does is selecting all non-blank and non-formula cells and hides relevant rows all at once. If you are new to SpecialCells, record macro when using "GoTo" command (Ctrl+G).